# Как вывести записи из базы данных в tableWidget используя Pyside6/QT6?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtablewidget, pyside6

Пытаюсь реализовать интерфейс программы используя *Pyside6*. Нарисовал форму в *QT Designer*, создал тестовую базу данных написал небольшой **main.py**.

Не могу понять, как правильно написать код для построчного вывода данных из таблицы в `tableWidget`. Пытаюсь сделать это при нажатии на кнопку.

[image: Вывод данных]

Слева в терминале выведены **5** строк с `id` и названием. Справа в таблицу добавляется только **одна** строка. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в данной проблеме.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem
from new__form import Ui_MainWindow

from db import Author
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/stage')
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        session = Session()
        for author in session.query(Author).order_by(Author.author_id):
            print(author.author_id, author.name)
            for row in range(10):
                for col in range(2):
                    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(
                    row, col, QTableWidgetItem(f"({author.author_id},{author.name})")
                    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication()

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**new__form.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'new_form.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.0.4
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
if not MainWindow.objectName():
MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 631, 291))
self.tab_posetiteli = QWidget()
self.tab_posetiteli.setObjectName(u"tab_posetiteli")
self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.tab_posetiteli)
if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 2):
self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
__qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
__qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 1):
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
__qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
__qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, __qtablewidgetitem3)
__qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, __qtablewidgetitem4)
self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QRect(30, 10, 256, 192))
self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.tab_posetiteli)
self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(30, 210, 94, 28))
self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.tab_posetiteli)
self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QRect(190, 210, 94, 28))
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_posetiteli, "")
self.tab_prodaza = QWidget()
self.tab_prodaza.setObjectName(u"tab_prodaza")
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_prodaza, "")
MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 640, 30))
MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
# setupUi

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"id", None));
___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"FIO", None));
___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"test", None));

__sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Test Tesov", None));
self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Read", None))
self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Add", None))
self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_posetiteli), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Posetiteli", None))
self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_prodaza), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Prodaza", None))
# retranslateUi
```

**db**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Text, Date, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Topic(Base):
__tablename__ = 'topic'
__tableargs__ = {
'comment': 'Темы цитат'
}

topic_id = Column(
Integer,
nullable=False,
unique=True,
primary_key=True,
autoincrement=True
)
name = Column(String(128), comment='Наименование темы')
description = Column(Text, comment='Описание темы')

def __repr__(self):
return f'{self.topic_id} {self.name} {self.description}'

class Author(Base):

__tablename__ = 'author'
__tableargs__ = {
'comment': 'Авторы цитат'
}

author_id = Column(
Integer,
nullable=False,
unique=True,
primary_key=True,
autoincrement=True
)
name = Column(String(128), comment='Имя автора')
birth_date = Column(Date, comment='Дата рождения автора')
country = Column(String(128), comment='Страна рождения автора')

def __repr__(self):
return f'{self.author_id} {self.name} {self.birth_date} {self.country}'

class Quote(Base):

__tablename__ = 'quote'
__tableargs__ = {
'comment': 'Цитаты'
}

quote_id = Column(
Integer,
nullable=False,
unique=True,
primary_key=True,
autoincrement=True
)
text = Column(Text, comment='Текст цитаты')
created_at = Column(DateTime, comment='Дата и время создания цитаты')
author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('author.author_id'), comment='Автор цитаты')
topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topic.topic_id'), comment='Тема цитаты')
author = relationship('Author', backref='quote_author', lazy='subquery')
topic = relationship('Topic', backref='quote_topic', lazy='subquery')

def __repr__(self):
return f'{self.text} {self.created_at} {self.author_id} {self.topic_id}'
```

Comment: то есть ты серьезно предлагаешь разбираться в этом ужасно отформатированном коде?

Comment: Прошу прощения за это.

Comment: И ты даже не отредактировал еще.....

Comment: Можете подсказать как именно правильно оформить код? Я новичок здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не могу проверить ваш код, но я вижу что вы создав в таблице одну стоку

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
```

пытаетесь в методе `buttonClicked()` туда запихнуть все.

Я предложу вам попробовать следующее:

- ```
      self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
      ...
  ```
- ```
  def buttonClicked(self):
      session = Session()
      authors = session.query(Author).order_by(Author.author_id)

      for author in authors:
          print(author.author_id, author.name)

          row = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
          self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(row)

          self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(f"{author.author_id}")
          self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(f"{author.name}")
  ```

---

> void QTableWidget::**insertRow**(int row)
>
> Вставляет пустую строку в таблицу за строкой.

Comment: @MarcusStill вы попробовали то что я вам предложил?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это действительно работает!

Comment: @MarcusStill Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour